# regular expression - until you reach a specific character

Tags: regex

So for `www.test.com?pageToken=xyz&foo=bar` I want to get `pageToken` and its value until `&`;
I have tried `/(pageToken=).*[^&]/g`  but still it is getting all `pageToken=xyz&foo=bar` instead of just `pageToken=xyz`. what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need remove the in-between `.*` which greedily matches any character zero or more and then use negated character class `[^&]*` to match any character but not of `&`, zero or more times.

```
(pageToken)=([^&]*)
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/gV8gW7/3)

Answer (score 0):

You regex is too greedy because of `.*`. However, for getting param values you can use specific function. Here is one you can use:

```js
function getParameterByName(location, name) {
        name = name.replace(/\]/g, "\\\]").replace(/\[/g, "\\\[");
        var regex = new RegExp("[\/\?&]" + name + "=([^&#]*)"),
        results = regex.exec(location);
        return results === null ? "" : decodeURIComponent(results[1].replace(/\+/g, " "));
    }

    document.getElementById("res").innerHTML = getParameterByName("www.test.com/pageToken=xyz&foo=bar", "pageToken");
```

```html
<div id="res" />
```

Just change `name` to get the required param value from the strings like yours.